# How to retrieve value from clicked star on rating system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am working a project in PHP is dont really know much of ajax, javascript or json but i know i can do this if pointed to the right direction.

i have a form (POST) for review, on the form i have a 5 start rating, so far i have been able to make the starts change color at hover using this:

```
<div class=rating>
    <div class="star_1 ratings_stars"></div>
    <div class="star_2 ratings_stars"></div>
    <div class="star_3 ratings_stars"></div>
    <div class="star_4 ratings_stars"></div>
    <div class="star_5 ratings_stars"></div> 
</div>
```

on the javascript i have:

```
$('.ratings_stars').hover(

        // Handles the mouseover

        function() {

            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');


        },

        // Handles the mouseout

        function() {

            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');

        }

    );
```

on my css file i have

```
.ratings_stars
    {
        background: url('./images/star_blank.png') no-repeat; //images with blank star
    }

.ratings_over 
    {
        background: url('./images/star_overs.png') no-repeat; //colored star
    }
```

two problems i am having now are:

1. to be able to retain the class of '.ratings_over' on a star being clicked and those before it but not those after it.
2. to give each starts values, so when the 3rd one is being click, i should have a value being submitted along with the form (obviously i dnt think its possible)

Overall, i am thinking maybe to use checkbox for the rating so as to be able to submit the value along with the form but how will i implement hover effect on checkbox? or i will just make then check the boxes?

by changing the javascript to:

```
    $('.ratings_stars').hover(

        // Handles the mouseover

        function() {

            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');


        },

        // Handles the mouseout

        function() {

            $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_over');

        }

    );
```

the highlighted start is now being retained, is there a way to check how many hasClass with highted? then pass the value to php, maybe hidden input field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't actually need do use jQuery to handle the hover effect; that can be done with CSS only!

```
.ratings_stars {
   background: url('./images/star_blank.png') no-repeat; //images with blank star
}

.ratings_stars:hover {
   background: url('./images/star_overs.png') no-repeat; //colored star
}
```

Next, you can bind a `click` event to the starts, and handle logic there.  When you click a star, first we'll remove the `selected` class from all of them, and then just add `selected` to that one.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.ratings_stars.selected {
   background: url('./images/star_overs.png') no-repeat; //colored star
}
```

And to your JavaScript

```
$('.ratings_star').click(function() {
   $('.ratings_star').removeClass('selected'); // Removes the selected class from all of them
   $(this).addClass('selected'); // Adds the selected class to just the one you clicked
});
```

Finally, we need some way to hold on to the value.  There's a couple of ways to handle this.  One way would be to use jQuery's [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) method to run some custom code and then submit the form.  You could figure out which star is selected, and then send that up as data.

However, I'll suggest a simpler approach: add a hidden input field for the rating, and then update it whenever you click a star.

Add this to your form:

```
<!-- start the value at -1 so we know it hasn't been set yet -->
<input type="hidden" id="rating" name="rating" value="-1">
```

We'll use the HTML data attribute to store the value of a rating.  Change your stars HTML markup to:

```
<div class=rating>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="1"></div>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="2"></div>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="3"></div>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="4"></div>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="5"></div> 
</div>
```

Finally, we modify the click event handler:

```
$('.ratings_star').click(function() {
   $('.ratings_star').removeClass('selected'); // Removes the selected class from all of them
   $(this).addClass('selected'); // Adds the selected class to just the one you clicked

   var rating = $(this).data('rating'); // Get the rating from the selected star
   $('#rating').val(rating); // Set the value of the hidden rating form element
});
```

Now, when the form submits, you'll have the `rating` field which will either be -1 if they didn't select anything, or 1-5 if they did!

If the stars are the only thing in your form (i.e. there's nothing else to submit), you can forgo the hidden element and just issue a `$.post` right away from within the click handler.